# Programming a Timer with batch

Tags: batch-file

```
@echo off
:: Fiche 3 Exercice 3
Title Fiche 3 Exercice 3
color B4
Mode con cols=100 lines=40

set /p nbSecondeUser= Entrez un nombre de secondes pour votre timer : 
call :AfficheMessage %nbSecondeUser%

echo.
pause
exit

:AfficheMessage
set /a timerActuel=%~1

if %timerActuel% gtr 0 (
    echo Il reste %timerActuel% secondes
    !timerActuel!-=1
    timeout 1 > nul
    goto AfficheMessage
) else (
    echo Fin du timer
)
exit /b 0
```

*State :*
Programming a timer. The user enter a time (a number of seconds)
The script displays a message when this number of seconds has elapsed.
You are asked to :

- Use the function defined in the previous script;
- Program a repetition using a label, the "goto" command and an alternative;
- Do not use the "for" command;
- Do not use the "timeout" and "sleep" commands(1).
  (1) But you can use "timeout 1 >null" to wait 1 second

Can you help me a little bit please ????

Comment: The very first line in `:AfficheMessage` sets `timerActuel` to `%1`, and `%1` will always have the same value until you use `call` to change it. But there's nothing that says you can't add more labels. Also, your code to reduce `timerActuel` by 1 needs to use the `set /a` command.

Comment: ...and remember that `!variablename!` is the ***contents*** of `variablename` if `delayedexpansion` has been invoked, and a variable named `!variablename!` if `delayedexpansion` has not been invoked.

Comment: As an extension of the comment from @SomethingDark, ```!timerActuel!-=1``` is not a valid command or statement. I would assume that you meant to use ```Set /A``` somewhere before it. You should certainly validate that the input assigned to `nbSecondeUser`, is a valid integer string, before `call`ing a label to use it.

Comment: As a side note, only a complete coding imbecile would ask a user to run an exectuable file, with a one second timer, multiple times in a looping series, and expect it to be anywhere near efficient or accurate. There's one thing I'd expect though; using `C:\Windows\System32\timeout.exe`, or `%SystemRoot%\System32\timeout.exe`, or `%WinDir%\System32\timeout.exe`, should all improve things over `timeout` alone.

Comment: @Compo - I suspect this is homework meant to be an introduction to loops; sort of a "this is the awful alternative so that you appreciate features of the language" sort of exercise

Comment: I suspect therefore that the teacher / tutor is the imbecile. They clearly have little understanding of scripting if this is the type of thing they are setting as a learning exercise. It is counter intuitive, and does nothing in forwarding their students learning.

Comment: Thanks everyone for yours comments but i'm a begginer and i'm lost on my code.. i understand my  problem but i don't know how to fix it @SomethingDark I see that it's your thing batch file ...

Answer (score 0):

Thanks you everyone !

```
@echo off
setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
:: Fiche 3 Exercice 3
Title Fiche 3 Exercice 3
color B4
Mode con cols=100 lines=40

set /p nbSecondeUser=Entrez un nombre de secondes pour votre timer : 
call :calcTimeToSecondes totalSecondes
set /a finalTime=%totalSecondes% + %nbSecondeUser%


:AfficheMessage
call :calcTimeToSecondes totalSecondes
set /a timerActuel=%finalTime% - %totalSecondes%

if %timerActuel% gtr 0 (
    echo Il reste %timerActuel% secondes
    TIMEOUT 1 > nul
    goto :AfficheMessage
)
echo fin du timer
echo.
pause
exit

:calcTimeToSecondes
set heure=%TIME%
set heures=%heure:~0,2%
set minutes=%heure:~3,2% 
set secondes=%heure:~6,2%
set /a %~1=%heures% * 3600 + %minutes% * 60 + %secondes%
exit /b

    > Entrez un nombre de secondes pour votre timer : 4 
    > Il reste 4 secondes
    > Il reste 3 secondes 
    > Il reste 2 secondes 
    > Il reste 1 secondes 
    > fin du timer
    > 
    > Appuyez sur une touche pour continuer...
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).